# Passing JQuery object to Java method using DWR

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, dwr

I want to pass JQuery object `var $this = $(this);` to Java method using DWR, I'm doing something like that:

**Javascript Method**

```
function handlePieces($square) {
 $square.data('jumped').remove();
 if(player == 1){

        var user = $("#secondPlayer").val();
        DwrUtils.removeJumped(user, $square);
 }else if(player == 2){
        var user = $("#firstPlayer").val();
        DwrUtils.removeJumped(user, $square);
 }
}
```

**My Java Method in DwrUtils Class**

```
@RemoteMethod
public void removeJumped(String user, String square){
    UserLoginScriptSessionFilter filter = new UserLoginScriptSessionFilter(
            user);
    ScriptMethodInvoker invoker = new ScriptMethodInvoker("removeJumped",square);
    Browser.withAllSessionsFiltered(filter, invoker);

}
```

I have even tried to use `Object square` instead of `String square` in method parameters but it still doesn't work.

Should I convert it somehow to Json format or how can I do it ? I'm new to DWR so I don't know exactly how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either square should be a string or a json object for DWR to work.

So convert $square into json object and in the Remote method expect **Square square**

Comment: DWR has excellent documentation. Check http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/introduction/scripting-dwr.html and go in the end where it has example to pass a person object.